# Trello API - Get Organization's Boards with ID

Tags: api, trello

I have been working with the Trello API (pretty neat, btw), but I can't simply found why I can't get the list of boards of an organization. The documentation says that I have to make a call in the form of:

```
GET https://api.trello.com/1/organizations/myorganization/boards?key=<my_app_key>
```

But I keep getting an empty array as response. I am member of the organization that I want the boards from, but still, I don't see any boards.

If I try doing this but through the members (I can get my membership's boards), I get only a board that I created.

Thanks in advance for you comments!

Regards,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unless all of the boards are public, you will need to provide both an **application key** and a **token** authorizing you to see the boards in the organization.

> The application key is used only to let Trello know which application
>   is making the request; it doesn’t tell Trello who the request is being
>   made on behalf of. For example, if you’re using your own application
>   key, you still need to generate a token to be able to access any of
>   your private boards.

The "[**Getting Started**](https://trello.com/docs/gettingstarted/index.html)" guide includes a section on [**Getting a Token from a User**](https://trello.com/docs/gettingstarted/index.html#getting-a-token-from-a-user)

Comment: Thanks! that was exactly what I wanted to know =D I thought it wasn't necessary because the docs say the oauth token is optional =).

Comment: If developing a server-side application, you can get a user token that never expires likes this: https://trello.com/1/authorize?key=TRELLO_API_KEY&name=MyApp&expiration=never&response_type=token&scope=read,write